# Remotely access postgresql database

Tags: remote-access, postgresql, vps

I need to access a postgresql database from a remote machine on a VPS at DigitalOcean running 12.10 and postgresql 9.1.

How do I do this? I noticed port 5432 is closed, how do I open this?

Comment: Follow steps mentioned in http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/07/enable-remote-access-to-postgresql-database-server.html and change the port number present in postgresql.conf file. after changing port restart PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Url posted by @Jayesh did the trick. Followed instructions and succesfully made one of my development computers connect to another (from Windows with pgAdmin4 to Ubuntu 18.04 postgresql 10.9)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To open the port 5432 edit your `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` and change

```
listen_addresses='localhost'
```

to

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

and restart your DBMS

```
invoke-rc.d postgresql restart
```

now you can connect with

```
$ psql -h hostname -U username -d database
```

if you are unable to authentify yourself, then you need to give your user access rights to your database

Edit your

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

and add

```
host all all all md5
```

(This is for a wide open access. For stricter control, consult the [pg_hba.conf documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and adjust according to your needs).

Hereafter you need also a reload

```
invoke-rc.d postgresql reload
```

I don't need to mention that this is a basic configuration, now you should think about modify your firewall and improve the security of your DBMS.

Comment: In particular, you should enable SSL.

Comment: Okey, I tried this, but when I try to connect using pgAdmin from my computer, I get "Server not listening".

I added to iptables, and when I run iptables -L the following shows:
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:postgresql

When checking the IP and PORT on this site (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), it says the port is closed

Comment: is the server listening? check with `netstat -nlt|grep :5432`

Comment: I would insert the host row in a more strict way: `host <database> <user> <remote_client_IPaddress>/24 md5`

Comment: For Postgresql version 9.5 you may need to restart the server before the listen_addresses will take effect.

Comment: Check correct paths at server by PSQL with `SHOW hba_file;` and restart with standard `service postgresql restart`

Comment: When using Ubuntu 16 LTS with PostgreSQL v10, I solved (thanks DanielVérité and @Kethryweryn!) with `host all all all md5` . Need also do all [ssl-tcp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html) instructions, from  "To create a simple self-signed certificate..." first commands to "Finally, create a server certificate..." last commands.

Answer (score 30):

This does not work anymore, if it ever did :

> host all all * md5

The correct possible lines for this are :

> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 #ipv4 range
>
> host all all ::0/0 md5 #ipv6 range
>
> host all all all md5 #all ip

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: This definitely did the trick. The above answer definitely did not work.

Comment: Please @Mike express what is correct:  `host all all all md5` will work fine? It is correct?  any security problem?

Comment: @peterkrauss Yes, host all all all md5 worked for me. Security problem? Of course it is, but for what I was doing it was just fine. (Internal network)

Answer (score 4):

For the message "server not listening", that happen to me was, that i don't erase of # on the archive postgresql.conf 
i mean:

> #listen_addresses='localhost'

to:

> listen_addresses='*'

(Sorry for my english).

Answer (score 4):

> The highest-voted and accepted answer has serious security-impolications. This method is disabled by default for good reasons.

Better use local port forwarding with `ssh`:

```
ssh -L local_port:localhost:foreign_port user@server
```

---

Start the port forwarding:

```bsh
ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 user@your-server.com
#or
ssh -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 user@your-server.com
```

(Change local and foreign ports to fit your configuration).

Then you can directly connect to the database from your local computer:

```
psql -U db_user -p local_port -l
```

Comment: nothing else worked for me, other than that! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Following configuration, you need to set:

In  `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`

```
# Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

In `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

Restart your server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: This is a nice and short summary of the above answers.

Answer (score 1):

To open your port 5432, you need to run this command

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```